# How to do flood fill in texure paint (in blender 2.8)?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm doing texture paint and already paint some strokes but i want to reset it back to solid color . Where is the flood fill function ? i don't want to use the fill brush because it need couple of strokes to accomplish this task. Can i just reset the texture to black with single command ?

Comment: have you tried using the Image Editor commands to reload the image? Also, if you are painting in 3d view then you can fill the entire texture with one press by setting the strength to 1 with 0 pressure and dragging in the viewport.

Comment: Yes i use those commands , but not i'm looking for. The reload image can be used only if i haven't save the strokes. Also yes, i can paint with strength set to 1 but not efficient , i have to paint all over the object, if the shape is complex you have to rotate view and strokes couple of time. Why don't just make like that 'reload' button in image editor, something like 'reset' or 'flood fill' . just a single click and it should be done that fast. Actually i can do this using several solution but none of them is as fast as one ot two click.

Comment: Uh, turn off Occlude, Cull and Normal in Options tab and your Fill tool will flood completely - also turn up the strength to 1 with no pressure. If you save your strokes, there is no going back b reloading the image, that is true - so why did you save them then? Nothing different from any other image editor. Instead , load a new texture with 0 alpha after the initial texture and paint on that until you decide to keep the strokes.